# jQuery how to execute event only on the inner element

Tags: jquery, events, binding, live

Is there is a way to only let the inner element of a `listitem`
do something?

I have list elements that can contain `a` tags with a certain class.

The inner `a` tags are bound to a live click event handler.  The list items themselves have also a click event handler.

Something like this

```
<li>some text<a class="someClassName">some text</a></li>
```

with the handler for the `a` tags

```
$('#somelist li a').live("click", function(e)
```

and this is how the event for li item is added

```
$(markers).each(function(i,marker){
    $("<li />") 
    .html("Locatie "+'<a class="ol id"><strong>'+ids[i]+'</strong></a>') 
    .click(function(e){
          showLocation(marker, i);
    })
    .appendTo("#somelist ");
```

Comment: Could you please post more code? What is getting dynamically appended? Both the `a` and the `li`? Just the `a`? Is the click for the `li` using `bind()` and the `a` is using `live()`?

Comment: The li items are dynamicly added at the beginning There is an extra a tag added to the list items at a later stage when a checkbox is clicked. I check with hasClass wich one is clicked. I guess i have a bind and a live event then

Comment: ok, you are saying,I should use live consistantly. I can definitivly try that out, and also try out the solution from @Alex. I can be back later to verify if one or the other or both worked. Thank you both for the valuable input sofar.

Comment: Alex offered the key to an excellent solution. Please see his answer.

Comment: You shuld be wary of using 'return false'. Use e.preventDefault or e.stopPropogation instead

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `live` method in jQuery works via event delegation, which is the act of catching all the bubbled events from individual elements onto a common ancestor (in your case its `document`).

Stopping the propagation/bubbling of the click event occurs on the handler element (which is the common ancestor, not on the element itself) and exists way above the `li` that you are trying to avoid.

So by the time the `stopPropagation` method gets called, we've already traversed down the dom and passed the `li` element.

It's essentially putting a stop sign 200ft *after* the intersection.

So you'll either need to use `bind` and `stopPropagation` or find a different solution.

Here is an example of what I'm talking about: http://jsbin.com/ibuxo (check the console)

you can see the code or edit it at http://jsbin.com/ibuxo/edit

My suggested solution to this problem would be to use `bind` instead of `live`.

This requires you to do a little bit extra work, but it's not so bad.

You are probably using `live` because you are adding new elements, and you want them to have the same functionality. You should do this by binding them when you input them to the page. Here's an example

```
$(function(){
  var myAnchorHandler = function(e){
    alert('clicked!');
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
  };

  // initial bind
  $('#somelist li a').click(myAnchorHandler);

  // code where you input more li elements to the list with links
  $('#somelist').append(
    // bind your function to the element now, and then append it
    $('<li><a>hi</a></li>').find('a').click(myAnchorHandler).parent()
  );
});
```

Comment: good explanation, although I do not understand the termonology completely. Any ideas on diiferent solutions maybe, I am out off ideas at the moment.

Comment: I can go into more detail on it if you'd like, but more or less, if you want to be able to block something from happening on the `li`  you either need to use `bind` to handle your clicks, or you need to modify whatever handler is currently on the `li` to ignore anything that originated in a child anchor element.

Comment: no, you don't have to go into more detail, I can read up on that.
Right now, I am more interested in a practical solution.
I there something I can do in the li click event that would recognize
that I clicked on the child a element. I already try'd something with e.target, but that will only give the li element, right?

Comment: I added a simple example of how to use `bind` even though you're adding new elements to the list.

Comment: Sorry, put the comment in the wrong section at first
I can't evalute that fast right now, but thanks, If this is the solution. You are also saying that I dont need live at all in this setup.I am going to be pleasantly surprised if this works out because the content off the page is dynamicly added and I always thought you needed live for this to work

Comment: As long as you add event handlers to your elements, their events will be handled. In the case of dynamic content, you just have to wait until you put it there to get it to work. Another solution could be having a hidden element with all the events attached to it and running a `clone(true)` on it to return a new instance with the event handlers. That's if you don't want to write html in your code or something.

Comment: Not at all. Your solution works. You were absolutely right about using 'bind'. I didn't know that about 'live'. Thanks.

Comment: I just up-voted you, since you seem a little perturbed right now. Didn't mean to upset you. The core concept you are communicating in your answer is spot-on.

Comment: Thanks for catching the bug, it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution from Author:**

I added all the a tags like above, so no mixup with live anymore.

```
$(markers).each(function(i,marker){
    listitem = $("<li />") 
    .html("Location ") 
    .click(function(e){
        showLocation(marker, i);
    })
    .appendTo("#somelist");
    $("<a />")
    .html("<strong>"+ids[i]+"</strong>")
    .addClass('ol id')
    .click(function(){
        $('#ginfo').show();
        return false;
    })
    .appendTo(listitem);
```

Here is an interesting page to explain event bubbling: [How to stop event bubbling with jquery live?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967537/how-to-stop-event-bubbling-with-jquery-live)

Answer (score -1):

Have the handler for the `<a>` tags return false.