# Stop propagation with jQuery delegate/live function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, delegation

Here's the problem html:

```
<ul id="update-list">
<li class="update" onclick="window.location('some_url')">
  <h2> some header </h2>
  <p> some paragraph </p>
  <div>
    <a class="popup-link">
      <span> Show Popup </span>
      <span> + </span>
    </a>
  </div>
</li> 
// this repeats n times
//...
</ul>
```

When I click on `.popup-link` link, it should open the lightbox popup only (which it does) but the inline onclick on `li` also fires. The thing is that the `li` tags are all part of some partial which is fetched via ajax on different pages. So I use jQuery's `delegate` to bind the events as follows:

```
$('#update-list').delegate('.popup-link', 'click', function(e){
    // e.target is <span> while e.currentTarget is .popup-link 
    e.stopPropagation();
    //console.log(e.isPropagationStopped());  this shows 'true' in console
    $.popup();   // launch popup
    e.preventDefault(); // or return false
});
```

This doesn't seem to work and the inline `onclick` fires anyway. I've tried with `live()` as well but no success. Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop event bubbling with jquery live?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967537/how-to-stop-event-bubbling-with-jquery-live)

Comment: add "return false" to delegate function;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK you cannot reliably prevent an *inline event handler* from firing by stopping the bubbling within an *attached event handler*.

Furthermore, using `live()` or `.delegate()` you cannot use `preventDefault()` nor `stopPropagation()`. You need to return **false** to prevent the bubble phase and the default behavior.

Anyway, as I already mention you can't prevent the inline event handler to fire with that.

So either, create it completely `unobtrusive` (which is what I highly recommend) or remove that *inline click handler* in code.

**Example:**

```
$('#update-list').delegate('.popup-link', 'click', function(e){       
   $.popup();   // launch popup
   return false;
}).delegate('.update', 'click', function(){
   window.location('some_url');
})
// the rest of this is unnecessary if you can just omit the onclick attribute 
.find('.update')
  .removeAttr('onclick');
```

Ref.: [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Comment: hmmm...actually the links are created via server language tags: window.location("<%= url/param %>"). I know its obtrusive and not recommended but i guess i don't have a choice here. Would you suggest a solution (although its not part of this question)

Comment: @fenderplayer: it looks like Shog9 updated the post with a removal code for the inline handler. Anyway, it looks like `return false` does prevent the inline handler from firing (for me, Chrome 5)

Comment: I don't think `return false` will do much good with the inline handler there - by the time the event bubbles up to the handlers on `update-list`, it's already been through the handlers on the `<li>` elements below... [example](http://jsbin.com/ajizu3/2/) The inline handler will have to go.

Comment: @Shog9: Uh well, yes. I step back to my first opinion within the post. I thought it works because of a mistake from me on testing.

Comment: @Shog9 yeah... if i write: $('#update-list').delegate('.popup-link', 'click', function(e){       
   return false;
});
the inline click still fires

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('#update-list').delegate('.popup-link', 'click', function(e){       
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  // do something...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
$('#update-list').delegate('.popup-link', 'click', function(e){
    // e.target is <span> while e.currentTarget is .popup-link 
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault(); // or return false

     // open popup in a timeout so that this function can return false
    window.setTimeout(function() {$.popup();}, 20);

    // for IE
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    return false;
});
```

Comment: You need to `return` **false** withing live or delegate to prevent the default bevavior and bubbling.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this as `.delegate()` has been superseded by the `.on()` method.

It will work fine