# Jquery - Bind delegate to all "a" tags

Tags: jquery, event-delegation

i try to block the jq `click()` when you click on an link in a div.

**HTML**

```
<div id="all">
    <div id="test">
        <a href="http://google.de">google</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#test').click(function() { alert('only when i click the div');  });

$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $('body').append(e.target.href);
});
```

This code works great but my content is dynamically so i need a `delegate()` solution.

The code below dont work. But why? Whats the problem?

```
$('#all').delegate("a", "click", function(e)
{
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $('body').append(e.target.href);
});
```

**example**
http://jsfiddle.net/Lf3hL/13/

Comment: "dont work" isn't a very accurate description of a problem...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop propagation with jquery delegate/live function not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509249/stop-propagation-with-jquery-delegate-live-function-not-working)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

stopPropagation doesn't work with delegate - http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

> Since the .live() method handles events once they have propagated to the top of the document, it is not possible to stop propagation of live events. Similarly, events handled by .delegate() will propagate to the elements to which they are delegated; event handlers bound on any elements below it in the DOM tree will already have been executed by the time the delegated event handler is called. These handlers, therefore, may prevent the delegated handler from triggering by calling event.stopPropagation() or returning false.

Now if you change your test click to use a delegate and use [stopImmediatePropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/) it will work

```
$('#all').delegate('#test', 'click' ,function() {
    alert('only when i click on the div');
});    

$('#all').delegate("a", "click", function(e)
{
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $('body').append(e.target.href);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lf3hL/14/

Answer (score 2):

Because `delegate()` works by letting events bubble up, then handling them on the ancestor element (`#all` in your example).

So, because the events have already bubbled up, you can't stop them propagating at their source (because they must propagate to work).

Answer (score 1):

From the [jQuery `.delegate()` doc](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

> Since the .live() method handles events once they have propagated to
>   the top of the document, it is not possible to stop propagation of
>   live events. Similarly, events handled by .delegate() will propagate
>   to the elements to which they are delegated; event handlers bound on
>   any elements below it in the DOM tree will already have been executed
>   by the time the delegated event handler is called.

One possible solution is not attaching the event handler on the `a`, but on `#test` instead, and checking the [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/).

I've [updated your Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lf3hL/15/) with this method.

```
   $('#test').click(function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).is('a')) {
            alert('link was clicked');
        }
        else {
            alert('only when i click on the div');
        }

        e.preventDefault(); //just to cancel the link's default action
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The live and delegate functions are not able to handle the  `e.stopPropagation();` call in the same way 'normal' events would. From the delegate [docs](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) -

> Since the .live() method handles events once they have propagated to
>   the top of the document, it is not possible to stop propagation of
>   live events. Similarly, events handled by .delegate() will propagate
>   to the elements to which they are delegated; event handlers bound on
>   any elements below it in the DOM tree will already have been executed
>   by the time the delegated event handler is called. These handlers,
>   therefore, may prevent the delegated handler from triggering by
>   calling event.stopPropagation() or returning false.

Answer (score -1):

why not use the

```
.live()
```

function?

```
 $('a').live('click', function() {
     // Live handler called.
 });
```

that would add a click function to all the  tags that are added after the body is fully loaded.

Comment: `live()` and `delegate()` are essentially the same, with a few subtle differences on how they're handled internally.