# Calling a jQuery function when clicking on "body"

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a script that slides a div *out* of view when the user clicks on the background (the `<body>`).

Here's my code:

```
// Slide back out of view.
$('body').click(function(){
    $('.presentationArea').animate({'height': '0px'}, 1000);
});
```

But, see, here's the problem; If the user clicks ANYWHERE on the page, I.E. Menu links, buttons, textfields, images, the above function gets called! I only want it to be called if the user clicks the "body", you know, that thing BEHIND everything else? :) How would one do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I only want it to be called if the user clicks the "body", you know, that thing BEHIND everything else? :)

You can check [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target) and see if it's the actual `document.body` element. ([Live example](http://jsbin.com/ubari6)) But I suspect people are going to find it difficult to click that as opposed to (say) a `p` element, because the `body` doesn't typically fill the display area unless something is there to expand it (although you can do it with CSS).

But fundamentally, you can use `event.target` to see where the click was and decide at that point whether it's a click you want to handle (whether it was technically actually *on* `body` itself or something else you want to go ahead and treat the same way).

Alternately, you could hook up a handler to stop event bubbling via [`stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) on all of the elements you *don't* want clicked — e.g., for `a` elements:

```
$('a').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

`stopPropagation` just stops bubbling, not the default action (e.g., it doesn't keep people from following the link). But the side-effects of that might be a pain (I haven't done it globally like that, only targeted).

Answer (score 1):

You should check whether `e.target` is the `<body>` element.

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing "bubbling" your click will bubble from the child element all the way up to the parent and trigger the function.

See the answer on this thread for more details:

[How to stop event bubbling with jquery live?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967537/how-to-stop-event-bubbling-with-jquery-live)

Basically, you'll have to add a new function that on click has `return false` to stop the bubbling.

```
$('#wrapper').bind(void(0), false)
```

Should work assuming you have a wrapper div, as the second parameter "false" prevents bubbling.

Comment: Thanks! I've not heard of event bubbling before.

Answer (score 0):

use something like this:

```
// Slide back out of view.
$('body').click(function(event){
    if (event.target === this) {
        $('.presentationArea').animate({'height': '0px'}, 1000);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've got it:

```
  $("body").click(function(event) {  
    if(event.target.nodeName == "body" || event.target.nodeName == "BODY")
    {
      $('.presentationArea').animate({'height': '50px'}, 1000);
    }
  });
```

Comment: `if (event.target === document.body)`

Comment: Ah! Thanks @SLaks! That's much cleaner/betterer!