# Document click not working on dynamic element

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-extension, crossrider, kango-framework

**Content script:**

```
var $ = window.$.noConflict(true); // Required for IE

function startFunc() {

    $('a').mouseover(function(e){

        var anchor=this;
        var href=$(anchor).attr('href');

        if(href!='#'){

            $('.klik-me').remove();

            const xPos=e.pageX-20;
            const yPos=e.pageY-20;

            let $klikMe=$('<span class="klik-me">Click Me!!</span>').css({
                'padding':'5px',
                'background':'#000',
                'color':'#FFF',
                'font-size':'12px',
                'position':'static',
                'top':yPos,
                'left':xPos,
                'text-align':'center',
                'z-index':999999
            });

            $(anchor).append($klikMe);
        }

    });


}

$('body').on('click','.klik-me',function(){

    const href_in=$(this).parent().attr('href');

    kango.console.log(href_in);

    kango.dispatchMessage('storeHref', {href:href_in});
});


kango.addMessageListener('hrefSuccess', function(event) {

    kango.console.log(event.data.link);

});
```

**Background Script:**

```
kango.addMessageListener('storeHref', function(event) {

event.target.dispatchMessage('hrefSuccess', {link:event.data.href});

});
```

I am adding a pop up for all anchor tags on the page (this is working fine),i added a click event in Jquery(I love this) and using `kango.dispatchMessage` for sending message to background script. Nothing seems to be working.

Any help would be appreciated.

PS: i use to work with crossrider(Awesome) framework previously.

Comment: It should work for dynamic element. :=> 

$('body').on('click', 'klik-me', function() {
    // do something
});

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"Nothing seems to be working"*? Are there any errors in your browser's console?

Comment: on click function i am writing parent href to console i can't see it in console

Comment: You're going to need to try and stop the click event from a) bubbling up to your `<a>` element and b) triggering the default action which is to navigate to the `href` attribute value. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967537/how-to-stop-event-bubbling-with-jquery-live

Answer (score 0):

What I think is happening is the *click* event is bubbling up to your `<a>` element and triggering the default navigation action.

Stopping bubbling / default behaviour in delegated event handling is difficult. What I would do instead, is remove the `<span>` as a child of the `<a>`. For example

```
let $klikMe = $('<span class="klik-me">Click Me!!</span>')
  .css({ ... })
  .data('href', href) // set the href data into the <span>

$(document.body).append($klikMe) // append to body, not anchor
```

and in your click handler

```
$(document).on('click', '.klick-me', function() {
  const href_in = $(this).data('href')

  // then continue as in your original code

  return false // the click should have no default action
})
```

Answer (score -2):

Use the snippet below is what I'm reading everywhere, I can't get it working however.

Currently trying to do somewhat the same: [jQuery click event after new page loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47524288/jquery-click-event-after-new-page-loads)

Maybe it can be of some use.

Cheers.

```
$(parent).on('click', child , callback);
```